# Fill element from table with data from other table ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i am trying to fill element with data from database.

On click Ajax functions pull out 8 elements, in one of those elements i need to add data from other table at the same time. I did pull 2 deferent tables in one go with this:

```
 $new_rows = $this->postovi_model->get_next_10($offset, $numbdata);
        if(isset($new_rows))
        {
 $data['users'] = $new_rows;
            $this->load->view('user_rows_view_for_you', $data);
                $numbdata = "portfolio";
                $new_pips = $this->postovi_model->get_pips($offset, $numbdata);
                if(isset($new_pips)){
                    $data['users'] = $new_pips;
                    $this->load->view('user_rows_view_portfolio', $data);
                }
        }
```

But i have no idea how to make it so that data in $new_pips appear in specific element out of all that 8..

Im open to ideas

Comment: When you load view using `$this->load->view('user_rows_view_for_you', $data);` it never returns again to the controller.

Comment: @Hekmat it does if it shows both results... i just have no idea how to position it inside elements from 1st view.. both of this views are not the same, main view is called down at the bottom of script and its not presented in this code... this 2 views are parts ( rather elements in html ) that are shoved and filled with data then moved to main view. so both view  do execute ... i just dont know how to put 2nd view into 1st view

Answer (score 0):

You can return the HTML of a view like this :-

`$data['view_1'] = $this->load->view('view_1', $data, true);`

You could then use that in another view :-

`$this->load->view('view_2', $data);`